# How to cook with a metal disc on a treif glass top stove?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, how-to, cooking-bishul

The Star-K gives this advice for kashering a glass top stove: https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/kosher-appliances/2931/kashering-glass-corning-halogen-or-ceran-cooktops/

The sentence that I am asking about is: "it would be wise to place a metal disc, approximately 1/8 of an inch thick".

If anyone has tried cooking on a metal disc in this way, please tell me how it works, practically speaking.  My concerns are:
What type of metal disc?
Where to buy such a disc?
Does the disc mar mar or otherwise harm the stove top?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone who uses [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00012K5P2), but consult your rav to be sure this meets their requirements.

This product should be safe for stove, as per [this article](https://onthegas.org/tools-gadgets/heat-diffuser-for-glass-top-stove).

Comment: Based on your answer, I found this one that says it can be used with glass top stoves: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000W24RW8/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza